# How to delete a line from a variable?

Tags: vimscript, variables

Inside a function, saved multiple lines of external command output to a variable.
How to delete a line from the variable? Like first line.

I can run `let tmp = split(variable, "\n")` to assign the variable to a tmp list, then delete an item. Not sure if there is any easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this `substitute` command to delete, e.g the 3rd line

```
substitute(var, '\v^((.{-}\n){2}).{-}\n(.*)', '\1\3', '')
```

The regex works as follows

- `^((.{-}\n){2})` matches the first `2` lines and capture it in group `\1`
- `.{-}\n` matches the next line
- `(.*)` matches the rest of the variable and capture it in group `\3`

> `\{-}`    matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you get the result of your external command but you might be interested in [`:h systemlist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#systemlist%28%29).

It executes the command given as parameter and returns a list containing every lines of the output. You can then use [`:h list-functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#list-functions) on the result or simply `listVar[1:]`.

I think that is more robust and portable than matching the lines and doing some substitutions.

---

Here is an example:

```
" Get the result of ls has a list
let output = systemlist('ls')
echo output    " ['autoload', 'CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'doc', 'plugin', 'README.md']

" Remove first line
let output = output[1:]
echo output    " ['CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'doc', 'plugin', 'README.md']

" Remove README.md
call filter(output, 'v:val != "README.md"')
echo output    " ['CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'doc', 'plugin']

" Remove all *.md files
call filter(output, 'v:val !~ ".md"')
echo output    " ['doc', 'plugin']
```

See

- [`:h filter()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#filter%28%29)
- [`:h expr-!=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%21%3d)
- [`:h expr-!~`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%21%7e)

Comment: Could you show how such matchings and substitutions would look?

Comment: @mroavi I edited my answer with an example.